# Removed user gets an upvote

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I was able to upvote a user that seems to have been removed from the site, from 5 to 6 though the reputation did not show and could not confirm if 10 was added.

The username `mvdleij` and the question is [What is the easiest way to detect if at least one field has been changed on an HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598951/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-detect-if-at-least-one-field-has-been-changed-on-an-h)

Hope SO authorities would check this out.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just because the user has been removed does not mean you cannot like the answer that is still there.

Upvoting is not about reputation (although that is nice); it is about indicating what answers address the question best. In other words, you do not upvote a user, you upvote a post.

Comment: +1; it's about the answer. If it was about the user, I'd have negative rep.

Answer (score 13):

Posts from deleted users can be voted on like any other posts. The posts are no longer associated to the (deleted) account so there's no real reason to lock them or anything. Up/downvotes are for posts, not people.